# What is the relationship between constant-expression and conditional-expression?

Tags: c, constant-expression

I want to have a precise comprehension about the constant expression of C. So, I read the related provisions of C99. The first provision in chapter "6.6 Constant expressions" describes the syntax of constant expression, but I can't understand it.

The first provision in chapter "6.6 Constant expressions" of C99:

> *constant-expression*:
>   *conditional-expression*

Why does C99 use *conditional-expression* to explain *constant-expression*? No doubt, expression 2 + 3 is a constant expression. Is it a conditional expression?

Comment: It just means that it contains the grammar for `conditional-expression`. `conditional-expression` contains the definition for all the operators with higher precedence, so it means that a constant expression can comes from an expression that contains operators with precedence equal to or higher than ternary operator. But check the constraint also - since some operators are excluded (as you can use `()` to increase precedence of an operator).

Comment: A constant expression being evaluated at compile time must boil to a constant value that is in the range of its respective type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation “constant-expression: conditional-expression” is only a specification of the syntax of a constant expression. The syntax describes the strings that **may** be a constant expression. In addition to satisfying the syntax, a constant expression **must also** satisfy the constraints listed in clause 6.6.

The fact that the C standard uses “constant-expression: conditional-expression” may be confusing. However, it would be exactly the same if the standard used “constant-expression: expression”, as I will show below. That is, **any** expression is a constant expression provided it follows not just the syntax for expressions but also the constraints listed in clause 6.6.

One example of a conditional expression is `3 < 4 ? 5 : 6`. This expression is also a constant expression, because it satisfies the constraints in clause 6.6. On the other hand, `x < 4 ? 5 : 6` is also a conditional expression but is not a constant expression (assuming `x` is the name of an object and is not a macro that gets replaced by a constant, et cetera).

The clause 6.6 tells you that a conditional expression may be a constant expression if it satisfies the constraints. Clause 6.5.15 shows that a conditional expression may be either a `logical-OR-expression` or a `logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression`. Continuing to work through the chain, a `logical-OR-expression` may be the a `logical-AND-expression` or may be an expression built with the logical OR operator, `||`. Although the name at each level is something like `foo-expression`, each level is actually either the type of expression that came before or is an expression built with `foo`. It would just be cumbersome to name them `foo-expression-or-prior-type-of-expression` instead of just `foo-expression`.

Thus, the grammar starts with the primaries, which are identifiers, constants, string literals, and one special thing I will discuss in a moment, and the grammar builds those primaries into more complicated expressions, adding the possibility of using each operator that C permits. Layering the grammar in this way defines the operator precedence, because the earlier expressions must be parsed before the later expressions, where possible.

The special thing in the primary is a parenthesized expression, `( expression )`. The `expression` token is the end of the chain of definitions, defined in 6.5.17. This loops the grammar back; any expression can be placed in parentheses, which makes it a new `primary`, and then operators can be applied to it.

Clause 6.6 could have stated that a `constant-expression` is an `expression`, and it would have the same effect as saying it is a `conditional-expression`. This is because the constraints in 6.6 forbid assignment operators and comma operators. So, if we consider what an `expression` could be, clause 6.5.17 says it can be either an `assignment-expression` or `expression , assignment-expression`. But the constraint prohibiting the comma operator prohibits the latter. Therefore, an `expression` in a constant expression must be an `assignment-expression`. Similarly, an `assignment-expression` must be a `conditional-expression` and not `unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression`.

Answer (score 3):

To understand §6.6 Constant Expressions, you need to have understood something of the way the grammar works, and you need to read §6.5 Expressions.

Within §6.5 Expressions, section §6.5.15 Conditional expressions says:

> *`conditional-expression:`*
>           *`logical-OR-expression`*
>           *`logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression`*

This is the way that the standard specifies precedence, etc.  The idea is to exclude assignment operators and comma expressions from being 'constant expressions', but allows most of the rest, subject to the constraints defined in §6.6 (which, amongst other things, explicitly excludes assignment and comma operators, probably because the generic *expression* in the rule does include them).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the C standard does not explain anything. It tells how the C language is defined, but it does not tell the why.

The syntax sections are written in a special language (a variant of [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)) that is used to describe how a compiler should interpret C source code.
The specification

```
 constant-expression:
     conditional-expression
```

essentially means that a constant expression uses the same syntax as a `conditional-expression`. In the section about the conditional operator (6.5.15), you will find a similar syntax section defining how a `conditional-expression` is built up.

If you trace all the syntax rules, you will find that a `constant-expression` can use any operator except the assignment operators (`=, *=, /=, +=, -=, <<=, >>= &=, ^=, |=`) and the comma operator (`,`) (unless they are enclosed in parentheses).

Comment: I think that someone is in a bad mood. My answer might have been wrong, but your answer isn't, and I think that you have explained it better than anyone else.

Comment: The statement that the syntax rules show that a `constant-expression` can use any operator except assignment or comma is false. `(3, 4)` uses a comma operator and is syntactically a `constant-expression`.

Comment: I think Eric's complaint comes from the difference between plain syntactic analysis (where one ignores the extra constraint not easily expressible as grammar is written out as text) and taking both the syntax and constraint into consideration. The syntax rules (without constraint) would allow assignment and comma operator in the expression, but a valid constant expression should not contain them according to constraint.

Comment: @nhahtdh: No, my criticism was that the statement about syntax was false, just based on syntax alone.

Comment: I removed the down vote, but I do not think this answer answers the question literally asked in the question, “Why does C99 use *conditional-expression* to explain *constant-expression*?” In fact, the standard could have written the production as “constant-expression: expression”, and it would have been clearer that a constant expression is syntactically *any* expression but must follow the constraints listed after the syntax. Likely the reason the standard uses this production is that, to somebody who understands the grammar, the production “constant-expression: expression” is wasteful…

Comment: … in the sense that it leads to two symbols (expression and assignment-expression) that can only be expanded in one way, leading to conditional-expression, so it is redundant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks for the explanation. I upvoted your answer as I think it is at least as good (if not better) than mine.